# Import a CSV file into MySQL workbench into a new table dynamically

Tags: mysql-workbench

I can import a CSV file data into a existing table in MySQL Workbench, using Load data infile , but what if I have a file with 25 columns, it becomes a pain to create a structure for such tables before importing.

Is there a way to import CSV files without creating the structure, like proc import in SAS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Try the new 6.3 release (currently in RC, soon to be GA) which comes with a new table data import/export feature that supports CSV and JSON data. It creates the table on the fly during import.