# Load csv into MySQL, using a new table

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I am using `phpMyAdmin` to load a CSV file into a MySQL table but, does the table have to be created before the load?

I have read that if the workbench is used ( [Import a CSV file into MySQL workbench into a new table dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672309/import-a-csv-file-into-mysql-workbench-into-a-new-table-dynamically) ) the latest version creates the table on the fly but, is this possible with `phpMyAdmin`.
Here is the code that doesn't work

```
load data local infile '/Users/...'
into table skin_cutaneous_melanoma
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
```

Error is:

```
#1146 - Table hospital.skin_cutaneous_melanoma' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Ah, ok, I overread that. Yes, of course, the table must be created first and have the correct field order or you also can specify the order in the query if the table differs from the csv-columns

Comment: @Ctx question updated and thanks...

Comment: @ctx is there any alternative to this?

Comment: That's hardly possible, it is asked too much for the database system to guess column names and types. If you have influence on how the datafile is created, you may create SQL statements which create a table and fill it and just source that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, phpMyAdmin can do this.

From the main page, look for the Import tab. This is, of course, how you expect to import any file including if you already have the database and table created, but if not phpMyAdmin creates a temporary database and table for you using generic names and best guesses as to the data types for your columns. Note that this is probably not the ideal structure, but is the best guess based on the existing data in your database. For best results, you'll probably want to put the desired column names at the top of your CSV file and select the corresponding option during import, or rename them after import (likewise with the database and table names) -- but it is absolutely possible to do the import to a new table.